# Saying kaddish for a year, years after death

Tags: sources-mekorot, kaddish, yahrtzeit

Someone found out that their grandmother, who passed away 7 years ago, didn't have anyone that said kaddish for her for the year after her passing. Is there any inyun now to say kaddish for a year (starting on her yarhzeit which is coming up soon.) Is there any source or this or someone that speaks about whether the practice is to say for a year or not in such a case?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that I've seen that the main inyun of saying Kaddish is to give relief to the soul who is being punished in Gehenom for their sins. Since punishment in Gehenom is only for a year max, daily kaddish recital isn't said beyond that time. To tie it to this case, it seems like there wouldn't be a reason for daily kaddish recital beyond this time, even if one did not recite kaddish regularly during the first year.

Answer (score 4):

Nitei Gavriel Aveilus2 [51:13](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=379) & [51:14](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=380) brings from the Elef L'Mateh and Shevet Sofer that one would not say past the year of death in such a case.